# Retrieve records into table using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Please, i need assistance to this code. I have a dropdown list,showing different type of accounts. I want to be able to display transactions belonging to those accounts on change events from the dropdown. I am able to do this, using the traditional php and ajax. But i am just learning the laravel frameworks and i am stuck.Please help me look and see where i am missing it or a better way of achieving this feat.

See View:

```
<form role="form">
 <div class="col-md-8">
 <select name="grpid" class="form-control" id="grpid">
    @foreach($account as $account)
    <option value="{{$account->code}}">{{$account->accountName}}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select></div><div class="col-md-4">
<button type="button" name="sbt" class="sbt btn btn-block btn-success"   id="sbt">Retrieve</button></div>
</form>
     </div>
    <br/>
     <br/>
   </h2>
   <div id="tableview"></div> 
  </div>
 </div></div>
@endsection
<script src="/mat/js/newJquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#grpid').on("change",function(){
  var sid = $(this).val();
  var div = $(this).parent();
  var op =" ";

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: '/postForm',
    data:{
       '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
       'selectedid': sid;
        },
        success: function(data){
        op+='<table>';
        op+='<tr><th>SN</th><th>Date</th><th>Account Type</th><th>Narration</th><th>Amount</th></tr>';
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          op+='<tr>';
          op+='<td>'+i+'<td><tr>';
          op+='<tr><td>'+data[i].transdate+'</td></tr>';
          op+='<tr><td>'+data[i].acctype+'</td></tr>';
          op+='<tr><td>'+data[i].accounts_code+'</td></tr>';
          op+='<tr><td>'+data[i].narration+'</td></tr>';
          op+='<tr><td>'+data[i].amount+'</td></tr>';
          op+='</tr>';
        }
         op+='</table>';
         div.find('#tableview').append(op);
       },
        error: function(){
          console.log("Error Occurred");
        }
    });

 });

 });
```

See postForm method of the Controller

```
 public function postForm(Request $request)
    {
       $data = Accounttrans::where('accounts_code',$request->selectedid)->get();
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

Route for the form:

```
Route::get('/openform','AccounttransController@openform');
Route::post('/postForm','AccounttransController@postForm');
```

Kindly help. I want to display the result in a table format.

Comment: Can you provide you data structure taht you get in the ajax success ?

Comment: @SKJajoriya: it is not displaying any data at all. Infact,it just show blank page after the selection form the dropdown. That is why i am asking if there is abetter way of achieveing this

Comment: Use console.log to see actually what is the data that you are getting back. It might give you a clue.

Comment: @T.Shah: I have use console.log(data), but it does not show anything. However, when i use console.log(sid), it gives the id for the dropdown item.This shows, that i am targetting and getting the input, but it does not return anything when processed. Please, is there a better way to get data from databased based on a selected item in a dropdown list using laravel?

Comment: First make sure that your ajax is returning the correct data. To do that, just return a simple message from ajax and use console.log in success part to confirm that you are receiving proper data.

Comment: @T.Shah: thanks for this. I ahve seen what the issue is. I did not add csrf field to the form, and the model name was not correct. Now, using console.log(data), i can see the proper output. but now, it is not displaying in the table above. How will i display the rows in tabular form. pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form role="form">
   {{csrf_field()}}
 <div class="col-md-8">
 <select name="grpid" class="form-control" id="grpid">
    @foreach($account as $account)
    <option value="{{$account->code}}">{{$account->accountName}}</option>
    @endforeach
 </select></div><div class="col-md-4">
<button type="button" name="sbt" class="sbt btn btn-block btn-success" id="sbt">Retrieve</button></div>
</form>
     </div>
    <br/>
     <br/>
   </h2>
   <div id="tableview"></div> 

</div>

</div></div>
@endsection
<script src="/mat/js/newJquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#grpid').on("change",function(){
  //var sid = $('#grpid option:selected').val();
  var sid = $(this).val();
  //var div = $(this).parent();
  var op ="";
  console.log(sid);
  //var table  = '<table>';

  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: '/postForm',
    data:{
       '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
        //'selectedid':sid 
       'selectedid': sid//$('select[name =grpid]').val(),
        },
        success: function(data2){
        op+='<table class="table table-striped">';
        op+='<tr><th>SN</th><th>Date</th><th>Account Type</th><th>Account Code</th><th>Narration</th><th>Amount</th></tr>';
        for(var i=0;i<data2.length;i++){
          op+='<tr>';
          op+='<td>'+(i+1)+'</td><td>'+data2[i].transdate+'</td><td>'+data2[i].acctype+'</td><td>'+data2[i].accounts_code+'</td><td>'+data2[i].narration+'</td><td>'+data2[i].amount+'</td></tr>';
        }
         op+='</table>';
         $('#tableview').html(op);
         //console.log("Data Correctly Processed");
          console.log(data2);
       },
        error: function(){
          console.log("Error Occurred");
        }
    });

 });

 });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching parent of '#grpid' i.e. 'col-md-8' and stored it in 'var div'. In you ajax success function you are trying to find '#tableview'. But from the html it is visible that '#tableview' is not inside 'col-md-8' i.e. is parent of '#grpid'. So, either you take '#tableview' inside 'col-md-8' or you can simply use the following:

```
$('#tableview').append(op);
```

Comment: thanks so much. I am sorry, i should have updated this. I have been able to get this done by : first making all the rows to be one rows with different table data<td> and return$('#tableview').html(op); just like whta you are suggesting now. All the same thanks. Thumb Up. I have posted the coorect version include the jquery issue below