# Table cells returns with "undefined" ,when trying to populate with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Im new to Jquery and Ajax .I have a dynamic select option in my view blade and then Im trying to populate HTML table by passing  with selected value  to the controller( in laravel ) and getting the details of the selected values

I have tried to do this with JQuery and Ajax with (post url)  but my table is only getting filled "undefined" , please help me to figure out the mistaks in my code

my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $( "#dtl" ).click(function() {
    var value = $("#hotelname :selected").val();
     $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('Rooms.maketable') }}",
        method:'POST', 
        data : {value:value},        
            success: function (data) {
              // console.log(data);
            $('#datatable tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
            var html = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                html += '<tr>'+
                            '<td>' + data[i].hotel_id + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].available_date + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].singlerooms + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].doublerooms + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].deluxrooms + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].deluxdoublerooms + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].superiorsuitrooms + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                }   
            $('#datatable tr').first().after(html);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
});
});
```

two methods in controller

```
public function showform()
    {
        $hotelname  =  hotels::all();
        return view('admin.hotelrooms.index',compact('hotelname'));
    }
 }
    public function makeTable()
      {
        $data = hotelroom::where('hotel_id', '=', $request->get('value'));          
        return Response::json($data);
    }
```

my routes

```
Route::get('/home/Rooms', 'Admin\RoomsController@showform')->name('Rooms');
Route::post('/home/Rooms', 'Admin\RoomsController@makeTable')->name('Rooms.maketable');

expected to fill my HTML blank table with data receive from hotelroom table
but its only getting fills with "undefined" in every cell
```

Comment: `success: function (data) {// console.log(data);` <- can you show data's value

Comment: nothing in console , it only shows the code :(

Answer (score 1):

You try to access request object which is not available inside your method. update your makeTable method like below, make sure you import `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`
on top of your controller.

```
   public function makeTable(Request $request)
    {
        $data = hotelroom::where('hotel_id', '=', $request->get('value'))->get(); //  add get() function here         
        return Response::json($data);
    }
```

Comment: added both but still same

Comment: This is how select data    <option value="">Choose Hotel </option>
                     @foreach($hotelname as $c) 
                     <option value="{{$c->hotelid}}">{{$c->hotelname}} </option>
                     @endforeach

Comment: Try to learn how to debug ajax request. maybe this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447188/laravel-5-8-likes-system-with-ajax-post-request-not-working/55449487#55449487

Answer (score 1):

add this to your query `->get();`

```
public function makeTable()
      {
        $data = hotelroom::where('hotel_id', '=', $request->get('value'))->get();          
        return Response::json($data);
    }
```

also press ctrl+shift+c on your keyboard to monitor if your script is executing

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support , i manged to get it work by studying this code ( similar question)
[Retrieve records into table using Ajax in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997290/retrieve-records-into-table-using-ajax-in-laravel)